# Автозагрузка скрипта

Tags: php, denwer

Доброго времени суток! Мне надо, чтобы при запуске **denwer** автоматически запускался **php** скрипт. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: а как вы денвер запускаете?

Comment: через иконку start denwer на рабочем столе

Comment: мне в голову приходит только .bat-скрипт с двумя строчками, одна - денвер, вторая (если денвер форкается, конечно) php-скрипт. если не секрет, зачем оно так нужно?

Comment: не знаю насколько это правильно, но мне нужно, чтобы работал tcp сервер на сокетах и обрабатывал мои запросы

Comment: ещё подробнее, пожалуйста. Не обрывками, а связно. Вам нужен сервер на сокетах, висящий на 80-м tcp порту и обрабатывающий ваши http-запросы php-скриптом?

Comment: не на 80 порту, а на 2000 например(на любом редко используемом), и не http запросы. Мне нужен сервис с набором API, к которому я могу подключаться с различных клиентов - сайта или мобильного приложения. Запросы я буду передавать тоже через сокеты.

Comment: понятно, а где тут роль php-скрипта?

Comment: нет, вообще нужно чтобы по определенному ip по 2000 порту постоянно прослушивал соединение мой сервер, клиент отправляет строковый запрос и получает данные в виде массива

Comment: Я возможно ошибаюсь, но вроде денвер не умел перевешиваться на другие порты?Но суть даже не в этоп. Апач и так слушает порты, на которые натравлен.И при  поступлении запроса запускает нужный скрипт Например index.php). php-скрипты не крутятся постоянно. У большинства хостеров даже стоит ограничение на время исполнения скрипта